# Can't seem to get a side menu working

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, frameworks

I'm building a simple School Roster app for Android.
Everything is working fine so far, but I can't seem to fit in a side menu.
[This is the menu I want build in.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/)

The code I have at the moment. (index.html)

```
<body ng-app="rooster">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
      <h1 class="title"><strong>MV3Ci Rooster</strong></h1>
    </div>

    <ion-content id="push" padding="true">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <a href="maandag.html">
                <div class="item">
                <div style="float:left;">Maandag</div><div style="float:right;">10:15 - 14:00</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="dinsdag.html">
                <div class="item">
                <div style="float:left;">Dinsdag</div><div style="float:right;">12:30 - 15:45</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="woensdag.html">
                <div class="item">
                <div style="float:left;">Woensdag</div><div style="float:right;">08:30 - 11:45</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="donderdag.html">
                <div class="item">
                <div style="float:left;">Donderdag</div><div style="float:right;">08:30 - 15:45</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="vrijdag.html">
                <div class="item">
                <div style="float:left;">Vrijdag</div><div style="float:right;">08:30 - 15:45</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>  

    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-calm wit">
    <a style="color: white !important; padding: 7px 5px !important;" href="http://www.roelofplas.nl">roelofplas.nl</a>
    </div>

    </body>
```

The directions from the link I included are a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to get started with ionic siudemenus is create ready-made app sidemenu templates application , for this run command `ionic start your-app-name sidemenu` in command line, this will create a basic application with side-menu. There you can see how side-menu is handled in ionic application.Please go through code of that application. In general side-menus need to be enclosed in `<ion-side-menus>` directive, full example

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Right menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this without reading your comment. Altough it was excactly what I did so I mark it as accepted awnser. Thanks for the help, u had a very clear awnser that was excactly what I needed haha.

Comment: Thanks, i am glad you were able to solve on your own. This answer might help someone else :)